# post cloudera hadoop installation -- No CDH version detected. Check Again

Tags: hadoop, installation, cloudera

I failed starting `scm-agent` services on a single node `hadoop` cluster on a `VM`. After a long search, the underscore in `hostname` was removed, all packages were uninstalled, and re-installation went well.
However, I am now seeing an error:

> No `CDH` version detected. Check Again.

One of the solutions mentioned on other portals was `yum info |grep my version` which actually is in no direction.
Can someone point out what could have gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

yum list|grep your version

then  yum removed all the prvious versions.

https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Cloudera-Manager-Installation/Cluster-Installation-Detecting-CDH-versions-on-all-hosts/m-p/30090#M5105